# Extract numbers from a string & convert into an array in hive

Tags: arrays, regex, hive

I have string column in my hive table and I would the output to be in the following way:

```
Column A                 Column B
ddjj3332 jjn32212 334334 (3332, 32212, 334334)
```

I have tried to do regex replace in the string to remove the alphabets. But I am unable to convert it into an array.

Let me know if this is possible.

Comment: It would be a good idea to include a code sample in your post, to demonstrate that you have made some effort toward solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split` to make an array after you perform the replace:

```
split(regexp_replace(column_a, '[^0-9 ]', ''), ' ')
```